# write a process in mssql where I will extract data from tables and query it out to flat file

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to write a process in mssql where I will extract data from tables and query it out to flat file.  Which is the best approach to do this?  should I use bcp or osql?  I can't opt for ssis as the company has no budget to get BIDS.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select name from sysobjects" queryout "c:\tempexportfile.txt" -c -T -SYourServerName'
Exec master..xp_cmdshell 'type "c:\tempexportfile.txt" >> "c:\mainexportfile.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you.  I opted for bcp.